# SupportMapFragment doesn't start on SDK 10

Tags: android, supportmapfragment

I created an Android application which uses the SupportMapFragment.
Now I have to be able to use it on SDK 10 as well.
Although this is really an outdated version, I'm obliged to use it...

When starting the activity with the SupportMapFragment, the app crashes with this error message:

```
04-25 14:47:15.160      537-537/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{lokeren.viae.com.lokeren/com.viae.notification.activity.MapActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #21: Error inflating class fragment
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #21: Error inflating class fragment
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:581)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:626)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:626)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:207)
        at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)
        at com.viae.notification.activity.MapActivity.onCreate(MapActivity.java:100)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.fragment in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/lokeren.viae.com.lokeren-1.apk]
        at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:471)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:549)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:66)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:568)
```

This is my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<permission
    android:name="com.viae.notification.maps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="10"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />


<uses-permission android:name="com.viae.notification.maps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<!-- TEST -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    android:required="false" />
<!-- android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.-->
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:exported="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/logo"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name="com.viae.notification.activity.MapActivity"
        android:label="Lokeren">
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.viae.notification.activity.NotificationActivity"
        android:label="Melding">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.viae.notification.activity.MapActivity" />
    </activity>

    <service
        android:name="com.viae.common.service.impl.LocationService"
        android:label="@string/viae_location_service_name"></service>

    <service
        android:name="com.viae.notification.database.service.impl.NotificationService"
        android:label="@string/viae_notification_service_name"></service>

    <provider
        android:name="com.viae.notification.database.provider.NotificationProvider"
        android:authorities="com.viae.stad.lokeren.Notification"
        android:exported="false" />

    <provider
        android:name="com.viae.notification.database.provider.NotificationImageProvider"
        android:authorities="com.viae.stad.lokeren.NotificationImage"
        android:exported="false" />

    <provider
        android:name="com.viae.notification.database.provider.UrgencyProvider"
        android:authorities="com.viae.stad.lokeren.Urgency"
        android:exported="false" />

    <provider
        android:name="com.viae.notification.database.provider.CategoryProvider"
        android:authorities="com.viae.stad.lokeren.Category"
        android:exported="false" />

    <provider
        android:name="com.viae.notification.database.provider.CountryProvider"
        android:authorities="com.viae.stad.lokeren.Country"
        android:exported="false" />

    <provider
        android:name="com.viae.notification.database.provider.CityProvider"
        android:authorities="com.viae.stad.lokeren.City"
        android:exported="false" />

    <provider
        android:name="com.viae.notification.database.provider.AddressProvider"
        android:authorities="com.viae.stad.lokeren.Address"
        android:exported="false" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="xxxxxx" />
</application>
```

And this is my activity configuration:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<!-- The main content view -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/google_map"
            class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/menu"
            class="com.viae.notification.activity.MenuFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
<!-- The navigation drawer -->
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:gravity="bottom|center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/swipe_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?
'cus as I read in the documentation, this should be available on SDK 10 too...

Comment: is this a full exception you get? does it have `Caused by`?

Comment: I'll update the stacktrace

Comment: Google play service-lib have imported this library

Comment: stacktrace is added.

Comment: So I need an "uses library line" in the manifest for the service-lib?

Comment: I get now the error that google play services is missing. But it is my gradle file.

Answer (score 0):

I had a double fragment block inside my activity: layout file.

When I remove it, I get a null google map:

this results in null:

```
map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.google_map)).getMap();
```

while this is my layout file now

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<!-- The main content view -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/google_map"
            class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
<!-- The navigation drawer -->
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:gravity="bottom|center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/swipe_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I found that google play services is not added to the app. But it is in my gradle file